# QsqlQuery::exec: database not open (PyQt4 on Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtsql

Actually this question had ever been answered in this forum, but my problem still have not yet been solved by using the ways from the answers. I use PyQt 4, Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. I want to make connection to the database on mysql driver and execute query from the database with running this script:

```
def carimethod(self):
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL', 'MyFirstConnection')
    db.setHostName('127.0.0.1')
    db.setUserName('root')
    db.setPassword('tree')
    db.open()
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
    query.exec_("select * from datamd.fklim71")
    return True
```

When I run the script on ubuntu terminal, it return

> QSqlQuery::exec: database not open

I can't execute the query, how to solve this problem?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the output of `print(db.open()); print(db.lastError().text())`?

Comment: @ekhumoro , the output said 
`QSqlQuery::exec: database not open`
`True`

Comment: Try adding: `db.setDatabaseName('mydbname')`. Obviously you will need to use whatever the correct name is for your database.

Comment: I tried add db.setDatabaseName('mydbname') but it return the same result as before

Comment: But is `mydbname` the actual name of your database? As I said, you will need to use the correct name, not just some random string of letters.

Comment: Yes, I changed mydbname with my database's name